# SQL query returns null Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a sql query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.quantity)-SUM(IF(ISNULL(b.quantity),0,b.quantity)) AS stock 
FROM wp_wpsp_inventory_items a, wp_wpsp_assigned_inventory b 
WHERE a.master_id='9' AND 
     (CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.quantity) 
           THEN '' ELSE a.master_id=b.master_id 
      END)
```

There are two tables `a` and `b`. Table `a` stores all the inflows and the table `b` stores all outflows. Here I'm trying to calculate the stock by subtracting outflows from inflows. But there are situations when there is no entry of an Item in Table `b` is such case the query returns `NULL`. I tried using `IF()`and `ISNULL()` but nothing worked. Please help

Comment: A query itself never returns `NULL`, but an empty result set instead. So what is the real question? Do you ask about how to handle that case in your application?

Comment: In the above querying I'm querying quantity for `master_id=9` but in some cases, my 2nd Table `b` has no entry for `master_id=9`

Comment: Yes, that can be possible. But why is that a real problem?

Comment: Surely the other way around is also a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use left outer join.

```
SELECT SUM(a.quantity - coalesce(b.quantity, 0)) AS stock
FROM wp_wpsp_inventory_items a 
LEFT JOIN
wp_wpsp_assigned_inventory b
ON a.master_id = b.master_id
WHERE a.master_id = '9'
```

Comment: Syntax Error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.master_id = b.master_id
WHERE a.master_id = '9' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5`